# Gradient Boosting - taking advantage of known interactions

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, boosting

When using a gradient boosting method is there a way to take advantage of interactions I'm already aware of?

For example, say I have variables A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2

I know gbm will look for interactions, but if I already know that:

1. A1, A2, A3, A4 are likely to interact with each other.
2. B1, B2 are likely to interact with each other
3. the A's are unlikely to interact with the B's.

Is there a way to take advantage of this user information to improve the model or find a model more quickly?

One idea I had was to create new variables like C12 = A1+A2, C21 = A2-A1 but I worry that I'm just bloating the problem with redundant information.

Any recommendations?

Comment: You can try to do PCA on your input data before running a gradient boosting. Running PCA should give you a covariance matrix which should encode variable relationships. If the data confirms your observations, then you can pass that data as-is (I think). If not, and you still want to have that information added (e.g. you have little training data, you can modify that covariance matrix and get the projected data out with the new covariance matrix. The new features should have that prior knowledge in. In bayesian setting it is much more natural to do things like these but I digress...

Comment: I think gb samples features when constructing the tree; eg sklearn has the `max_features` option. If you could then somehow control which features are sampled together, you might be able to sample ones that you know interact together and therefore find the interaction more easily? Eg sample As togther, sample Bs together.